# delete filled rectangle c#

Tags: c#, drawing, gdi

I am making an external map for a video game. Therefore I am drawing a rectangle inside of a picture box. I redraw the rectangle every 1/10 second using a timer. Now my question is: How can I delete the old rectangle before drawing the new one?

Comment: It would help to see the code you actually have

Answer (score 1):

You should do your drawing within an event handler for your `PictureBox`'s `Paint` event, using the `Graphics` object passed via the `PaintEventArgs`.  Then the clearing and repainting of the PictureBox's background will be done for you every time the `PictureBox` repaints its contents.  Then, instead of calling your draw method or whatever every 1/10 second, you can just call `yourPictureBox.Invalidate()` every 1/10 second.

Comment: Can you please give me more informationon how to do that?

Comment: @darude_cod3r Move your drawing code inside of `PictureBox_OnPaint()`

Comment: You can add a `Paint` event handler via the form designer.  Select your `PictureBox`, then in the Properties window, click the "Events" button (looks like lightning).  Scroll down to the `Paint` event.  Double-click.  This will add an event handler method to your code and take you to that point in the .cs file.  Move your drawing code into that method, but use `e.Graphics` rather than the `Graphics` object you would otherwise create.  If you need more detail than that, it's Google time.

Comment: There problem is, that your suggestion only works when i scroll the picure box. As soon as I stop my square dissappears...

Comment: Did you update your timer `Tick` event handler to call `yourPictureBox.Invalidate()`?

Comment: I got it working using the timer... My only problem now is, that my squares flicker. What did you mean by update the timer Tick event handler?

Comment: I mean that formerly you were doing your drawing on every tick of the timer.  Now that your painting code is in the `Paint` event handler, you need to change what you're doing inside your timer's `Tick` event handler: instead of your drawing code, that method should now contain a call to `yourPictureBox.Invalidate()`.

Comment: Have you tried setting yourPictureBox.DoubleBuffered to true?